# MvxCollectionViewController with Sections

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Using Xamarin.iOS and MvvmCross, I am trying to create an `MvxCollectionViewController` that contains Sections, with each Section consisting of a title and a collection of `MvxCollectionViewCell` (based on the MvvmCross tutorial http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/n11-collectionview-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html).

I have subclassed `MvxCollectionViewCell` as set out in the tutorial. I have the following Model and ViewModel hierarchy (adapted from the tutorial):

```
public class Kitten    
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
}
```

the ViewModel for each Section:

```
public class KittenSectionViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private string _sectionName;
    public string SectionName
    {
        get { return _sectionName; }
        set { _sectionName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => SectionName); }
    }

    private List<Kitten> _kittens;
    public List<Kitten> Kittens
    { 
        get { return _kittens; }
        set { _kittens = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Kittens); }
    }
}
```

and then the ViewModel for all the Sections:

```
public class KittensViewModel: MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IKittenService _kittenService;

    public List<KittenSectionViewModel> KittenSections { get; set; }

    public KittensViewModel(IKittenService kittenService)
    {
        _kittenService = kittenService;
    }

    public override void Start ()
    {
        KittenSections = _kittenService.GetKittens().ToList();
    }
}
```

The `KittenCollectionCell` is basically unchanged:

```
public KittenCollectionCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
{
    _loader = new MvxImageViewLoader(() => MainImage);

    this.DelayBind(() => {
        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<KittenCollectionCell, Kitten>();
        set.Bind(NameLabel).To(kitten => kitten.Name);
        set.Bind (_loader).To (kitten => kitten.ImageUrl);
        set.Apply();
    });
}
```

And lastly I have implemented a custom `MvxCollectionViewSource`, which I assign to the CollectionView's Source:

```
public class KittenCollectionViewSource : MvxCollectionViewSource
{
    KittensViewModel KittensViewModel { get; set; }

    public KittenCollectionViewSource (KittensViewModel kittensViewModel, UICollectionView collectionView, NSString defaultCellIdentifier) : base (collectionView, defaultCellIdentifier)
    {
        this.KittensViewModel = kittensViewModel;
    }

    public override int GetItemsCount (UICollectionView collectionView, int section)
    {
        return KittensViewModel.KittenSections [section].Kittens.Count;
    }

    public override int NumberOfSections (UICollectionView collectionView)
    {
        return KittensViewModel.KittenSections.Count;
    }

    protected override UICollectionViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
    {
        return collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (DefaultCellIdentifier, indexPath) as KittenCollectionCell;
    }
}
```

(The full solution is available at https://github.com/mrtnkrstn/SectionedKittenCollectionView.git).

The problem is that the `KittenCollectionCell` needs to bind to a `Kitten`, but because the model is wrapped inside a different viewmodel, I don't know how to tell the `MvxCollectionViewSource` to use the inner model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of your source looks fairly simple - so I think  all you are missing is the `GetItemAt` override - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Views/MvxCollectionViewSource.cs#L75

I think you'll need to add something like:

```
    protected override object GetItemAt(NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (KittensViewModel == null)
            return null;

        return KittensViewModel
                      .KittenSections[indexPath.Section]
                      .Kittens[indexPath.Row];
    }
```

You might also be able to implement `KittensViewModel` as:

```
   protected KittensViewModel KittensViewModel { get { return base.ItemsSource as KittensViewModel; } }
```

Comment: Thanks @Stuart you are a legend. I used to pass the datasource in the ctor and did not know that I have access to ItemsSource. You made my day :)